# Samba changes file ownership! How do I get rid of that problem?

Tags: permissions, samba, sharing, file-sharing, share

I am running a Samba Server (Version 3.5.6). The file sharing is **OK** until I realize that Samba changes file ownership when another user (*not the original owner*) edit the file and saves it. This is particularly true, if I have set `admin users` parameter to administrate the share.

The strange thing is **only the file ownership** get changed but 'directory ownership' remain unchanged (which is desirable) :)

Options like `force user` and `force group` are not going to work here because, sharing directory have a different sub-directories that belong to many users.

**Configuration for the share looks like this**

`[staff]`

```
    comment = "Staff members only"
    path = /path/to/staff
    browseable = yes
    valid users = @staff, @managers, @moderators
    write list = @staff, @managers
    create mask = 0640
    directory mask = 0750
    admin users = @moderators`
```

As you can see, members in above-mentioned groups are allowed to read others data but **only** members of *@moderators* can do changes to file & directories.

Problem arises when a member of *@moderators* modifies a **file** (not a directory) that belong to another user (belong to *@staff* or *@managers*), the ownership of that edited  file changes to ***root***!!! which is **totally undesirable**.

I want to preserve the ownership of the file to its original creator even after a member of *@moderators* modifies it. **How Do I Achieve This???**

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "admin users" for the file modifications, because members of this setting operate as root on the filesystem. Quoting from smb.conf man page:

> admin users (S)
>   This is a list of users who will be granted
>   administrative privileges on the share. This means that they will do
>   all file operations as the super-user (root). You should use this
>   option very carefully, as any user in this list will be able to do
>   anything they like on the share, irrespective of file permissions.

Comment: I know that fact but why Samba change owner of a file to "root"? That was  my problem!

Comment: I observed the file ownership changing when a certain user has write permissions in a directory but the file itself is not writeable by the group. Looking at your create and directory mask I would guess this is the case. Try to give the group write permissions on the files and make the directory sticky and set-gid (+t +s). Still I don't recommend using the "admin users" group for working with the files.

Answer (score 1):

I think the parameter you're looking for is inherit owner (S). Here's the description from the Manual page for smb.conf 5

```
inherit owner (S)

       The ownership of new files and directories is normally governed by effective uid of the connected user.
       This option allows the Samba administrator to specify that the ownership for new files and directories
       should be controlled by the ownership of the parent directory.

       Valid options are:

              •   no - Both the Windows (SID) owner and the UNIX (uid) owner of the file are governed by the
                  identity of the user that created the file.

              •   windows and unix - The Windows (SID) owner and the UNIX (uid) owner of new files and
                  directories are set to the respective owner of the parent directory.

              •   yes - a synonym for windows and unix.

              •   unix only - Only the UNIX owner is set to the UNIX owner of the parent directory.

       Common scenarios where this behavior is useful is in implementing drop-boxes, where users can create and
       edit files but not delete them and ensuring that newly created files in a user's roaming profile directory
       are actually owned by the user.

       The unix only option effectively breaks the tie between the Windows owner of a file and the UNIX owner. As
       a logical consequence, in this mode, setting the the Windows owner of a file does not modify the UNIX
       owner. Using this mode should typically be combined with a backing store that can emulate the full NT ACL
       model without affecting the POSIX permissions, such as the acl_xattr VFS module, coupled with
       acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes. This can be used to emulate folder quotas, when files are exposed only
       via SMB (without UNIX extensions). The UNIX owner of a directory is locally set and inherited by all
       subdirectories and files, and they all consume the same quota.

       Default: inherit owner = no
```

Here are some other parameters that set permissions:

create mask, directory mask, force create mode, force directory mode, inherit permissions (S)